# Armor increasing strength

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, alternate-history, ancient-history, armors

Many games have various side bonuses on their armors other than just defense. 
These bonuses can often be active things like having a ghost thrall to protect you when wearing a special armor or more passive bonuses like ''+15% strength''.

Leaving aside the active bonuses, how can an ancient armor directly increase ones strength when wearing it? Is it actually possible without ''magic'' or high futuristic technology ?

Comment: im guessing you mean other than the "strength" of protection?

Comment: yeah ,exactly I mean physical strength as to be able to put more speed,power and explosiveness into movements, specially during combat.

Comment: You mean like a medieval version of a [powered exoskeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_exoskeleton)?

Comment: indeed if it can be achieved by pre-industrial cultures

Comment: I don't know whether adding weight to increase momentum would work?

Comment: wouldn't increasing weight of the armor decrease the speed therefore nullifying the effect ?

Comment: if you can cause enough damage, you dont need to be the quickest (and from my experience dont the games with this sort of thing in them have either a fast or strong factor rather than both (fast but not as strong and vice versa)?)

Comment: makes sense, good point

Comment: it also allows for tension and prevents an overpowered, invincible entity.

Comment: Would some manner of flexible material that somehow compresses easier but expands with more energy than normal be stronger? That would theoretically improve your movements since everything would take less effort for you. It doesn't exist in reality but in an alternate reality perhaps there's a weird kind of rubber that's been found? Sorry if this is a bad comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Less strength penalty = strength bonus?**

Here is a way super armor could improve strength without invoking magic.  It improves strength in comparison to other armored situations.

Suppose you have 16th century plate armor.  It will protect you.  It will also slow you down and limit what else you can carry, because it is heavy.  Your primitive plate armor comes with a strength penalty.

Now you have 22cond century nanofiber / polymer armor.  It protects you as well as the plate armor did, but you have a minimal strength penalty or none at all.  Compared to your situation wearing the plate armor, the high tech armor has increased your strength.

Neither of these armor situations increases your strength as compared to you wearing only your gold lamé shorts, nor do these armored situations get you looking any better than you do in those shorts.

Comment: "*Neither of these armor situations increases your strength as compared to you wearing only your gold lamé shorts*" then, by definition, they don't increase your strength.

Comment: @RonJohn: Assuming you make $20,000 each month, which situation contributes to your increasing wealth more: paying 22% on your credit card interest every month, or paying 12% on your credit card interest every month?  Hint: the answer does not depend on how much credit card debt you carry unless you carry 0 in which case you are wearing the gold lamé shorts .

Comment: "*which situation contributes to your increasing wealth more*" That question makes no sense.  It's akin to "not even wrong".

Comment: *Less strength penalty = strength bonus?* is a very good point. Consider  a 30 kg suit of full plate armor with a bad fit, i.e. a lot of the weight is supported by the shoulders only, and mobility is impeded, vs. a well-tailored suit of full plate with the same weight, which is well  distributed over your body, and mobility is less impeded.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from @Willk 's great answer, if the armor is actuated somehow. Steampower, Electric cirquits or just plain magic to help move the joints and make your movements harder to stop with outside forces would fulfill the requirements.

Regardless of what you pick, magic is going to be involved somehow to shortcut some requirement. Steampower for example would need too much water and fuel to work comfortably unless you have guys running after you carrying water and fuel or magic it somehow, and any actuator would need computing power to keep the movements in line with yours and smooth.

Answer (score 2):

**Biotech.**

The only real technology needed here is a basic knowledge of Electricity and Muscle Anatomy (of course much more than a basic understanding is needed if you want to make this more realistic).

Think the "Pickle-Rick Fights Rats" sequence from Rick and Morty, where he makes himself a suit of armor that enhances his strength without any advanced technology, only the advanced knowledge to construct it.

But that's the big problem with the idea. It really depends on what type of Ancient Empire made the armor. An Atlantis-type society of science well ahead of their time would really be the only type to come up with something like this, anything else would just be unrealistic (unless a single brilliant ancient scientist had a remarkable amount of free time).

Even if it's not the most realistic, it's the only somewhat-plausible solution without incorporating Magic or Technology I can think of.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuildin *Sydney*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

> Many **games** have various side bonuses on their armors other than just defense.

Right:

## Games

Where breaking the laws of physics in the name of fun is perfectly doable.

> how can an ancient armor directly increase ones strength when wearing it? Is it actually possible without ''magic'' or high futuristic technology ?

Make no mistake: **It can't.**  There's no way that loading on lots of **dead weight** (whether as plate mail -- weight: 27kg -- or a leather or iron curiass -- only 3 kg) will make you stronger while wearing it.

[image]
https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3408/3327580382_5d898f4104_b.jpg

[image]
https://www.outfit4events.com/runtime/cache/images/redesignProductFull/pef-6003b.JPG

Answer (score 1):

It's all a matter of chemistry and biology.  Starting in the 19th century people began isolating and identifying [Anabolic Steroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabolic_steroid#History), but they had been in use (from animal gonad sources) long before they were chemically identified.

Your "magic" armor is either biological (shells/leather/other tissues) or is otherwise treated with biological material.  It naturally secretes the hormones stored while the animal was alive, imbuing those who wear it for any length of time with increased strength.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not in the very truest and most technical sense, but consider the case of compression clothing.

Compression clothing is believed to improve performance and recovery times when exercising and many people swear by it. However according to this [article](https://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/01/14/can-compression-clothing-enhance-your-workout/), there is little to no evidence to suggest this is the case, or why it would be the case.

And here's the important bit; despite there being no evidence and no reason why it would improve your performance, those people who believe in it feel they perform better. In other words it's a placebo effect.

Now I doubt modern compression clothing is possible in an historic setting and I'm not sure old fashioned corsetry could do the job, but really it doesn't need to. You don't need your armour to actually do anything (though something noticeably different about it would probably help) all you need to do is tell your warriors their armour has been enchanted by the most powerful mages in the land, or blessed by their gods, and they will *feel* stronger.

It may not be the kind of effects games prescribe to magic items, but it could still give that performance boost.